# Wrong vector return type for Rust function

Tags: generics, vector, return, rust

```
pub fn collect_prime_factors(number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut prime_factors = Vec::new();

    for i in 2..number {
        if number % i == 0 {
            collect_prime_factors(number / 2);
            prime_factors.push(i);
            prime_factors
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
lib.rs:14:9: 14:22 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `collections::vec::Vec<i32>`
(expected (),
    found struct `collections::vec::Vec`) [E0308]
lib.rs:14         prime_factors
```

I do not get the problem here. I am declaring a `Vec<i32>` as return type. Why is the expecting those empty braces?

Why does this not work only when I use it within a loop? When I remove the loop and only `return prime_factors;` everything works fine.

Comment: What's the call to `collect_prime_factors(number/2)`  for? It computes a new vector and throws it away.

Comment: semantically wrong I only realized it after rust told me those new issues. please ignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems (other than the paste error).

The error you quote is not for the function's return value; it's the value of the `if` *expression*:

```
pub fn collect_prime_factors(number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut prime_factors = Vec::new();

    for i in 2..number {
        if number % i == 0 {
            prime_factors.push(i);
            prime_factors   // This would be the value of the if
        }
    }
}
```

Rust is expecting there to be no return value, or alternatively a value of `()`, but you're returning `prime_factors`.

If you fix this, you'll then see that the next error is the reverse, that it's expecting the function to return a `Vec<i32>` but you're returning `()` (nothing).

I think the correct thing here is to return the vector at the end of the function once all the factors have been collected:

```
pub fn collect_prime_factors(number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut prime_factors = Vec::new();

    for i in 2..number {
        if number % i == 0 {
            prime_factors.push(i);
        };
    }
    prime_factors  // Return the vector from the function.
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4caeabe253bb6883a5f45db44c39f825&version=stable&backtrace=0)

(But this function doesn't actually return only prime factors!)

Comment: The next iteration of the function would be `(2..number).filter(|&i| number % i == 0).collect()`; still not producing prime factors ;-)

Comment: But why is there an expectation of nothing / empty tuple?  Is it because the for loop does not know how to handle return values of an expression?  And if I would use the 'return' keyword...would that be a fix (cannot write code atm)

Comment: I found this discussion: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/961 . Basically I think it comes down to it not being obvious that returning a value from a loop (especially as the final expression) makes sense. As it's currently an error it could be added in to Rust in future if/when there's agreement.

Comment: @xetra11, `for` as an expression has unit value `()`, just like almost all statements do. Because the loop is the last statement in the function, the compiler assumes that you return unit from the function, while it is declared that the function must return `Vec<i32>`. That's what the error is about. Naturally, you cannot return values from a loop directly, because it is unclear how exactly it should be handled. `return` works, however, because it is specifically intended to return a value from a function early; however, if you use it, you'll of course find that your loop finishes prematurely.

Comment: @xetra11 make sure to upvote answers that were useful and accept the answer that most helped you solve the problem.